# Why 64-bits aligned XOR do not run faster than 32-bits aligned XOR?

Tags: memory, xor

I want to test the speed of two block of memmory， and I did a experiment in a 64 bits machine(4M cache), and XOR two region of memory with 32-bits aligned and 64-bits aligned respectively.I thought the 64-bits aligned region XOR counld much faster than 32-bits aligned region XOR, but the speed of two types of XOR are quiet the same.

code:

```
void region_xor_w32(   unsigned char *r1,         /* Region 1 */
                       unsigned char *r2,         /* Region 2 */
                       unsigned char *r3,         /* Sum region */
                       int nbytes)       /* Number of bytes in region */
{
    uint32_t *l1;
    uint32_t *l2;
    uint32_t *l3;
    uint32_t *ltop;
    unsigned char *ctop;

    ctop = r1 + nbytes;
    ltop = (uint32_t *) ctop;
    l1 = (uint32_t *) r1;
    l2 = (uint32_t *) r2;
    l3 = (uint32_t *) r3;

    while (l1 < ltop) {
        *l3 = ((*l1)  ^ (*l2));
        l1++;
        l2++;
        l3++;
    }
}

void region_xor_w64(   unsigned char *r1,         /* Region 1 */
                       unsigned char *r2,         /* Region 2 */
                       unsigned char *r3,         /* Sum region */
                       int nbytes)       /* Number of bytes in region */
{
    uint64_t *l1;
    uint64_t *l2;
    uint64_t *l3;
    uint64_t *ltop;
    unsigned char *ctop;

    ctop = r1 + nbytes;
    ltop = (uint64_t *) ctop;
    l1 = (uint64_t *) r1;
    l2 = (uint64_t *) r2;
    l3 = (uint64_t *) r3;

    while (l1 < ltop) {
        *l3 = ((*l1)  ^ (*l2));
        l1++;
        l2++;
        l3++;
    }
}
```

Result:
 [image: speed comparation]

Comment: From left to right, that's the L1 cache, L2 cache and RAM bus speed you are measuring.

Comment: You are right, but the why the speeds of 32-bits aligned and 64-bits aligned in a 64 bits machine are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to data starvation. That is, your CPU is so fast and your code is so efficient that your memory subsystem simply can't keep up. Even XORing in a 32-bit aligned way takes less time than fetching data from memory. That's why both 32-bit and 64-bit aligned approaches have the same speed — that of your memory subsystem.

To demonstrate, I've reproduces your experiment, but this time with four different ways of XORing:

1. non-aligned (i.e. byte-aligned) XORing;
2. 32-bit aligned XORing;
3. 64-bit aligned XORing;
4. 128-bit aligned XORing.

The last one was implemented via [_mm_xor_si128()](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_integer_logical.htm), which is a part of the SSE2 instruction set.
[image: Speed of different ways of XORing (optimized binary)]

As you can see, switching to 128-bit processing gave no performance boost. Switching to per-byte processing, on the other hand, slowed everything down — that's because in this case **memory subsystem still beats CPU.**

Comment: Thanks, did you add compiler optimization '-O2' when you compiled your codes?

Comment: Yes, I did. BTW, without `-O2`, 32-bit aligned xor *is* slower than its 64-bit counterpart (at least that's what I get on my machine). Again, this is because, with suboptimal code, the CPU becomes a bottleneck.